# selected="selected" applied for all select options in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-select

While switching between dropdown values in Angularjs Select directive, only the ng-model value is updated. But in browser console selected class wont be changed. How to change the selected value?
see this example http://embed.plnkr.co/lqMR0Yl2hjVQ9qPfcbBd/

After selecting option "one" in dropdown in browser console the selected="selected" value wont be changed.
see this screenshot.[image]

why selected="selected" value is not updated for the respective selected option in dropdown?how to do this?

Comment: well angular select directive onLoad it set's dom selected='selected' only if something selected by default and it wont re-construct the `dom` like a ng-repeat .

Comment: i need to update the dom element too, how to externally re construct dom element?

Comment: do you mind explaining why you need that, there might be a possible neat alternative .

Comment: one way is using jquery to manipulate dom sample here https://plnkr.co/edit/ix5vhMY9yDYBJzsFzlfW?p=preview .

Comment: does it solve your case . feel free to add as a answer if you fond a proper solution, it might help someone .